# Bash script generates 'hash hmac' different then PHP

Tags: bash, encryption, openssl

#### Problem

my command script generates `sometimes` different result then PHP `hash_hmac` command. Can somebody explain or show an example how it should be done.

The script generates username based on timestamp. An example of username that generates a different result: `1611134116:admin`

#### Full Script

```
<?php
$secret="XXXXXXXXXXXX";
$user = "admin";
$ttl = 24 * 3600;  // Time to live
$time = time() + $ttl;
$username = $time . ':' . $user;
$password = base64_encode(hash_hmac('sha1', $username, $secret, true));
$password2 = base64_encode(hash_hmac('sha1', $username, $secret, true));

$result2 = base64_encode(hash_hmac('sha1', $username, $secret, true));
$result = exec("printf %s $(printf %s " . $username . " | openssl dgst -sha1 -hmac " . $secret . " -binary) | base64");

echo $username;
echo "<br><br>";
echo $result;
echo "<br>";
echo $result2;
echo "<br>";
echo ("Is equal: " . (($result === $result2) ? "true" : "false"));
echo "<br><br>";
echo $password;
echo "<br>";
echo $password2;
echo "<br>";
echo ("Is equal: " . (($password === $password2) ? "true" : "false"));
```

#### Problematic part

```
$result = exec("printf %s $(printf %s " . $username . " | openssl dgst -sha1 -hmac " . $secret . " -binary) | base64");
```

`Note:` that problem only occurs when output is generated as binary and that is really important for me.

I tried using `echo -n` and stopped using `variables` but the problem persists.

Comment: Why the double printf? Why not just `printf %s " . $username . " | openssl dgst -sha1 -hmac " . $secret . " -binary | base64`?

Comment: looks like inner `printf` output a binary string feeded to `printf "%s"`, result is different than muru's proposal

Answer (score 1):

`muru's` comment did the trick, the problem was related to incorrect usage of `printf %s`.

#### Working code

```
$result = exec("printf %s " . $username . " | openssl dgst -sha1 -hmac " . $secret . " -binary | base64");
```

Thank you for your time.